# Setting input text field with watir-jquery

Tags: watir, watir-jquery

I am trying to set the value of a text input using `watir-jquery` selectors. I find that it only works with watir's `text_field` selector. My questions are:

1. How to set input fields using `watir-jquery`
2. What is watir's `text_field` selector, and why does its result have different methods than the same field found by the `input` selector?

The relevant code follows:

```
require 'watir'
require 'watir-jquery'
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'www.yandex.com'
jq_inp = browser.jq('input#searchInput')
jq_inp.value = 'Vlad the Impaler'
NoMethodError: undefined method `value=' for #<Watir::Input:0x007fd7f3c3cee0>
    from gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:553:in `method_missing'

wt_inp = browser.input(:id, 'searchInput')
wt_inp.value = 'Vlad the Impaler'
NoMethodError: undefined method `value=' for #<Watir::Input:0x007fd7f3c97b60>
    from gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:553:in `method_missing'

wt_tf = browser.text_field(:id, 'searchInput')
wt_tf.value = 'Vlad the Impaler'  # This works!
# So, let us try text_field with jquery
jq_tf = browser.jq('text_field#searchInput')
 => nil 
# No search thing as text_field in jquery
```

Answer (score 0):

Watir has a TextField object that is a subtype of Input, which supports set. So both

```
browser.jq('input#searchInput').to_subtype.set
```

and

```
browser.input(:id, 'searchInput').to_subtype.set
```

work.